# DCoder and php include files on Android

Tags: php, php-7

I've downloaded the DCoder app for Android on Google play hoping to code some php code on Android. However, I've created two php files in the top level directory and included one from the other with require_once. The result was that DCoder couldn't find the other file. Is it possible to include files with DCoder in PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new project feature release, Dcoder 3.0 now supports full fledged projects for many programming languages and frameworks. Linking files and using php server is also supported in Dcoder projects.